# The difference between submit a form from inner-form and outer-form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

As the code below, when click **btnInner**, alert 'submit', click **btnOuter**, no alert.
And then, click **btnInner**, alert twice.

refresh.

First click **btnOuter** n times, no alert, then click **btnInner**, alert n+1 times.

I want to know Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function login() {
        $('#form1').submit(function () {
            alert('submit');
        });
        //alert("submit after");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="login.html">
        <button id="btnInner" onclick="login()">inner submit</button>
    </form>
    <button id="btnOuter" onclick="login()">outer submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just do `$('#form1').submit(function (event) { event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't show alert because `login()` function in **btnOuter** is only attaching **#form1**'s submit event, but the function in **btnInner** is not only attaching an event, but it also trigger the event, because is located inside the form as `<button>` element.

If you put `login()` function in `<a>` element inside form, it only attach the event and will not trigger any submit event, because `<a>` is associated as link not submit form action.

Example:

```
<form id="form1" action="#">
    <a href="#" onclick="login()">Attach event</a>
    <button id="btnInner">Trigger event</button>
</form>
```

When you click **"Attach event"** link, you attached the event to the form, then alert will show if you click **"Trigger event"** button". Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/6r6TViWcxDOVhuiC6Va3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code handling event "submit"

it should trigger submit event you can do like this:

```
 function login() {
        $('#form1').submit();      

    }
```

you can handle submit here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#form1').submit(function () {
            alert('submit');
        });
});
```

Comment: this, does not answer what is questioned by @san, the **I want to know Why?** part, this is a simple workaround witch is not the propose of this question.

Comment: Answer is that: second button does not trigger submit

Comment: `$('#form1').submit(function () { });` is a hook to an event and it's not an invocation, only `$('#form1').submit();` should invoke it. The question is, in simple words, **why does the event registration get invoked?** and that, you're not answering...